# How can I export linked Projects from Project Online (Office 365) into a Project file instead of Excel?

Tags: microsoft-project

I'm trying to export a series of Project Online projects that have inter-project dependencies out of Project Online and into a locally saved Project file. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a local file that doesn't refer back to the Project Online projects.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to open the Project Online files in Project Desktop, perform something like a "save as" operation to save locally, and be done. Is this possible?

Asked another way: is there any way to export from Project Online to Project Desktop files without having the resultant files refer back to Project Online?

Comment: Are you able to save each of the subprojects as a local .mpp file? And the issue is that the links refer to the location in Project Online?